# Проблема с датой php

Tags: php

```
  $end_date = "12.05.2016-00:00";
            if($end_date > date('d.m.Y-H:i'))
            {
                echo "1";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "0";
            }
```

Он должен выдавать 1 а ставит 0,если использовать другую дату например: 20.05.2016-00:00 то он ставит 1

Comment: таймзоны настроены?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Это строки! Вы сравниваете не сами даты как таковые, а строки по правилам сравнения строк. Сравнивайте метки времени:

```
$end_date = strtotime("12.05.2016-00:00");
if($end_date > strtotime("now"))
{
    echo "1";
}
else
{
    echo "0";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо,заработало)

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать использовать [Datetime](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.datetime.php). Будет это примерно так:

```
$format = 'd.m.Y-H:i';
$end_date= DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '12.05.2016-00:00'); 
$now = new DateTime(); 
if($now < $end_date){
  return true;
}
return false;
```

Comment: У вас формат не верный тут, исправьте пожалуйста на `$format = 'd.m.Y-H:i';`

Comment: Вот этот вариант более точнее,время тоже сравнивается